# Getting array index out of bounds exception on this

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
String resultArr[] = response.split("&");
String[] values = resultArr;
String name[] = new String[values.length/2];

for(int i = 0;i<values.length-1;i++)
{
    if(i%2==0)
    {
        name[i] = values[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This works when values array have 2 values. I am able to print name array. When values array goes more than 2 , it gives me array index out of bounds exeption.

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting when you post, and give more details in the question - what have you done to diagnose this?

Comment: Thanks Jon for Editing. :).. I am trying to copy strings at position 0,2,4,6.. from "values" array to "name' array. It is throwing array index out of bounds. Length=3, Index =4

Comment: @user3477871: Right - that information should be in your question. Code-only questions are generally frowned upon; they're not much use to future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
name[i] = values[i];
```

Your `name` array is only half the size of your `values` array, but you're trying to use the same indexes. I suspect you want:

```
name[i / 2] = values[i];
```

Or more readably in my view:

```
// Note consistency of naming and how the type is specified 
String[] namesAndValues = response.split("&");
if (namesAndValues.length % 2 != 0)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uneven name/value pair length");
}
String[] values = new String[namesAndValues.length / 2];
String[] names = new String[values.length];

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
    names[i] = namesAndValues[i * 2];
    values[i] = namesAndValues[i * 2 + 1];
}
```

Comment: @Jon.. could you please help me for the logic of storing odd values as well just like above worked for storing even values

Comment: @user3477871: Did you actually read the second part of my answer? It shows how to extract both the names and values in one loop...

Comment: :- Was about to post the same :). And it worked inone loop itself !!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is basically storing all even values into name
But at the same time you are storing it only in even values of name.
Try this :-

`if(i%2==0)
            {
                name[i/2] = values[i];
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You have `name` array as half the size of `values` and you are iterating over `length` of `values` and assigning values to `name` array.

culprits are `String[] name = new String[values.length/2];` & `name[i] = values[i];`

If your `response` string contains a single `&`, your code would work, but for more number of `&` in your `response` container it would raise `index out of bound` exception.

Answer (score -2):

try changing String[] values = resultArr;
to this 
String[] values = resultArr[];